# Setting screen orientation to sensor landscape triggers two orientation changes

Tags: android

I am creating an app where I need to manually set screen's orientation to landscape and I've encountered a problem when I rotate device clockwise.

**Case which works:** Imagine holding a phone in portrait mode and then start rotating it counterclockwise. When you reach approximately half a way, phone would normally switch to landscape.

**Case which doesn't work:** The same situation but phone will be rotated clockwise. When you reach almost half a way, phone would rotate to landscape but it would look like the landscape where I rotated phone counterclockwise and not clockwise. Everything would be opposite. If I rotate a little bit more, then it would switch to correct landscape.

My question is why is that happening in only one direction? I am setting my landscape orientation like this:

```
activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```

This should allow activity to know in which orientation it is. What do you think?